# Div открывается по 2х клику

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть код:

`<div class="car">car</div>
<button onclick="f1()">Close/Open</button>`

```
function f1() {
    var a = document.getElementsByClassName("car")[0];
    display = a.style.display;
    if (display == "none") {
        a.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        a.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

В css я прописал `.car{ display: none;}` По этому див `car` открывается только со 2-го раза, я конечно знаю что можно в html сразу в тег задать `style="display: none"` но в моей ситуации сделать это я не могу, (делаю проект в котором при большом экране див открыт а при маленьком закрыт и можно его открыть только с помощью нажатия на кнопку) Буду благодарен за ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var style = window.getComputedStyle(a);
a.style.display = style.display == "none"? "block" : "none";
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Answer (score 1):

Можно добавить второй класс-невидимку, и при клике переключать его.

```js
let car = document.querySelector('.car');
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  car.classList.toggle('invis');
});
```

```css
.invis { display: none; }
```

```html
<button id="btn">Close/Open</button>
<div class="car invis">car</div>
```